# Systemd-journald.service log rotation is not working

Tags: docker, systemd, journal

systemd-journald.service log directory grow and not stop at set value MaxLevelStore=800M. It seams that it is due to running docker containers on the server. Is there a good approach to control MaxLevelStore of systemd-journald.service when there are a lot of docker containers running on the host?

Comment: Try running `journalctl --vacuum-size=800M` and see if it helps

Comment: Also try setting `SystemMaxUse=100M` in `/etc/systemd/journal.conf`